# How do I get a specific tag value from an EC2 instance using Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2

Basically I want to get a specific tag value from an EC2 Instance. The EC2 instance has a *releaseId* tag key I want to retrieve, which is an integer. How do I get the releaseId value from the instance.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'net/http'

metadata_endpoint = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/'
instance_id = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( metadata_endpoint + 'instance-id' ) )
```

I have very limited Ruby knowledge and any guidance will be appreciated. After I get the current EC2 instance_id, what do I do to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag values are not accessible via instance metadata service. You have to use the public EC2 API [DescribeTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html).